# Jankins slave not connecting

Tags: jenkins, slave

With windows JNLP connection, slave is getting connected.
But when I convert it to windows service, it is giving below error.

[image]

Comment: What is the event log on a slave sais? Also please check whether the same user is used when rin as regular jnlp and service.

Comment: As it windows slave, I downloaded the jnlp file and launched it with admin rights.
It is shown as connected.
In the JNLP UI, there is FIle-->Install as service option.
Once I use this, the windows service is created and started running also..
But when I check in browser, it is showing the error shown

Comment: Please find the log files at below link.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e3xOhExOkO6ciTmpU_-Dwnl1kHWvhcDj

Comment: These are logs from master 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12ic_kXuPiz9tR6iMaXBTuJp0z2qKqNLI

Comment: How many java processes run on slave? - it sais  middleware01 is already connected to this master. Rejecting this connection...   also please check ConnectionRefusalException: Server didn't accept the handshake: - is it similar to your case ?  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41384

Comment: I tried to connect using jnlp file first..then we have option in ui to change it as service..then it is not working..